# filtering list of objects based on multi-selection dropdowns Javascript/Typescript/Lodash/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, lodash

I fot a bit of a complex issue on my hands that I would need your help.

I have multiple dropdown filters like location, category, subcategory e.t.c. My initial version is working where which ever combination is chosen, it will return the right result. My next challenge is to make the dropdowns with multi select. I am using firebase for this, trying to do a complex filtering on the client side.

I have list of objects like this that I get from the DB:

```
{
 data1: {
     status: true,
     location: "New York",
     category: "Food",
     subcategory: "Pizza",
     price: 24
 }
 data2: {
     status: true,
     location: "Chicago",
     category: "Food",
     subcategory: "Hot Dogs",
     price: 5
 }
 data3: {
     status: true,
     location: "Miami",
     category: "Food",
     subcategory: "Taco",
     price: 2
 }
}
```

In order this to filter by multiple values I have the following:

```
filter() {
  this.filteredData = _.filter(this.getListings, _.conforms(this.activeFilters)).filter(x => 
  x.status === true);
}
```

Then, I have a method that sets the active filters based on a condition or show all from that property by removing that active filter, for example:

```
filterLocation() {
const location = this.filtersData.get('location').value;
this.locations = [];

for(let i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
  if (location[i].itemName === 'All') {
    this.removeFilter('location');
  }

  if (location[i].itemName !== 'All') {
   this.locations.push(location[i].itemName);

   property = 'location';
   this.activeFilters[property] = val => this.locations.some(x => 
   val.includes(x));
   this.filter();
  }
}
}
```

And then, I have the same or similar method for category, subcategory e.t.c.

The thing I want to achieve now is for example I want to multi-select locations and categories or subcategories if needed but not to be limited to adding more properties in the future.

So, if I choose New York and Miami I want to get all items that contain those values but not to be limited if I want to filter by additional values like food, drink e.t.c.

This example works perfectly for filtering by single value, you can add up as many filters and combinations as you like, it will always return an array of objects matching what you selected from the dropdowns.

I am trying some stuff out, Ill update the question if I manage to solve it, in the meantime I appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: do you have any working example. Just want to see how the multi select is categorised

Comment: I replaced some of the selects with this multiselect, hope this helps for now: [https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/groupby](https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/groupby). I will try and setup an example as soon as I can. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I updated the filterLocation() method according to my solution. I am going to work on improving the filter now.